# How to format YearMonth and MonthDay depending on a Locale?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Formatting a `LocalDate` in Java 8 using a specific `Locale` can be achieved like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(myLocale).format(value);
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(myLocale).format(value);
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(myLocale).format(value);
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(myLocale).format(value);
```

Assuming `value = LocalDate.now()` this would result into:

```
// myLocale = Locale.ENGLISH
6/30/16
Jun 30, 2016
June 30, 2016
Thursday, June 30, 2016

// myLocale = Locale.GERMAN
30.06.16
30.06.2016
30. Juni 2016
Donnerstag, 30. Juni 2016

// myLocale = new Locale("es", "ES")
30/06/16
30-jun-2016
30 de junio de 2016
jueves 30 de junio de 2016
```

As you can see Java decides which delimiter ("-", ".", "/", " ", etc.) to use and how to sort the date elements (e.g. month before day or vice versa, etc - in some locales it could be that year comes first, etc.).

**My question is:** How can I format a `java.time.YearMonth` and `java.time.MonthDay` depending on a `Locale` like the example above?

Based on the example I would expect results like this...

... for `YearMonth`:

```
// myLocale = Locale.ENGLISH
6/16
Jun, 2016
June, 2016
June, 2016

// myLocale = Locale.GERMAN
06.16
06.2016
Juni 2016
Juni 2016

// myLocale = new Locale("es", "ES")
06/16
jun-2016
de junio de 2016
de junio de 2016
```

... for `MonthDay`:

```
// myLocale = Locale.ENGLISH
6/30
Jun 30
June 30
June 30

// myLocale = Locale.GERMAN
30.06.
30.06.
30. Juni
30. Juni

// myLocale = new Locale("es", "ES")
30/06
30-jun
30 de junio de
30 de junio de
```

Of course there could be other `Locale`s which use completely different delimiters and ordering.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way out. At least for Oracle JDK, the locale specific patterns are [hard-coded here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/text/resources/FormatData.java?av=f#805) and there doesn't appear to be a format with only month / year, or only day / month.

Comment: Thanks, it's a pity formatting `YearMonth` and `MonthDay` isn't supported native by Oracle JDK... :(

Comment: This would make a good feature-request. Unfortunately I believe Java 9 is feature-frozen now.

Comment: @BasilBourque do you know where do submit feature requests for Java?

Comment: Oracle has [this general page about how to report a bug or request a feature](http://bugreport.java.com/). But I suspect it would be more productive to go through the working site of the [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) experts: http://www.threeten.org/

Comment: See also using [my own format engine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39666326) for this purpose. Currently I am working on even better integration into java-time-package.

Comment: Here is the Java feature-request: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8168532

Comment: Also see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168532

Comment: See [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41850130/642706) on a duplicate Question, by the creator of java.time ('JodaStephen', Stephen Colbourne). See [feature request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168532) mentioned in comment by mkurz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this [Java-8-bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168532) cannot be fixed in Java-9 because even the [feature-extension-complete-date](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) is already over. Let's see if it is going to be fixed in Java-10 which is still a long time away...

Of course, as one answer here suggests, you could try to process a given localized date pattern in order to remove irrelevant parts. But I still consider this approach as errorprone because there are still so many locales around. And indeed, the accepted answer is flawed for Chinese. Localized literals are here the main problem. Maybe the accepted answer can be fixed at least for this important language, but you might also consider **two other libraries with good internationalization features which can solve your issue in a more reliable way**.

a) [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DateFormat.html#getInstanceForSkeleton-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstanceForSkeleton(DateFormat.YEAR_MONTH, Locale.CHINESE);
String output = df.format(new Date());
System.out.println("ICU4J=" + output); // 2017年1月
```

However, one problem is lack of interoperability with Java-8-types, especially `MonthDay` and `YearMonth`. A solution requires something like `Date.from(YearMonth.now().atDay(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());` Possible, but cumbersome.

b) my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (with the same data base as ICU4J)

```
ChronoFormatter<CalendarMonth> cf =
    ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.FULL, Locale.CHINESE, CalendarMonth.chronology());
CalendarMonth cm = 
    CalendarMonth.from(YearMonth.now()); // or: CalendarMonth.nowInSystemTime()
System.out.println("Time4J=" + cf.format(cm)); // 2017年1月
```

[Interoperability](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarMonth.html#toTemporalAccessor--) with Java-8 exists in the reverse direction, too. And the Time4J-counterpart for `MonthDay` is the class `AnnualDate`.

---

Side note: The accepted answer of @Julian yields for Chinese: 2017年1 (needs to be fixed)

Comment: Thanks Meno Hochschild! I tried your `time4j` library and it works. Only one question: Your example shows how to format year and month, but how do you format month and day (see my original question)? Can you give also an example how to do that? Thanks!
BTW: Looks like you work really hard and a lot on that library. You should advertise it a bit more maybe since I never heard of it before but looks quite promising.

Comment: Oh I forgot one question: Does your library somehow interfere with the JDK locale data - I mean in a way that it would replace the underlying locale data from the JDK or something like this? Is it completely save to use your library in a way it doesn't change the behaviour of any existing JDK 8/9 date code (or whatever) that already exists? I know e.g. that Java 9 now uses "Unicode Common Locale Data Repository" - CLDR for locale data now as default - time4j doesn't replace that, does it?

Comment: About your other questions related to Time4J: Indeed, I have invested a lot in that library. My family already complains sometimes ;-). but I have no commercial attitude and just do it for love for date and time. Unfortunately Time4J is not well known although its wealth of features deserves more attention. About i18n: Time4J and the JDK uses independent i18n-data which don't interfere at all. Not even in JDK 9. By the way, The CLDR-data of Time4J are still bigger because of extra support for types like `CalendarMonth`, `AnnualDate` and the many extra calendars. The JDK uses a subset of CLDR

Comment: Month and day - can be formatted via a formatter for the class [AnnualDate](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/AnnualDate.html). The javadoc contains an example how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Solution provided by gevorg is probably the simplest solution if you will use a limited list of Locale.

If you want to make it work with any Locale I would suggest to get a locale pattern and then remove the parts you are not interested in, once you have this pattern you should remove the part you are not interested in and use the resulting pattern to create your own DateTimeFormatter.

This is a full example of the idea explained above for `MonthDay`. In order to use it for `YearMonth` replace `keep.add('d')` with `keep.add('y')`. (and of course `MonthDay` with `YearMonth`)

```
ArrayList<Locale> locales = new ArrayList<Locale>();
locales.add(Locale.ENGLISH);
locales.add(Locale.GERMAN);
locales.add(new Locale("es", "ES"));
locales.add(Locale.US);
ArrayList<FormatStyle> styles = new ArrayList<FormatStyle>();
styles.add(FormatStyle.SHORT);
styles.add(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
styles.add(FormatStyle.LONG);
styles.add(FormatStyle.FULL);
ArrayList<Character> keep = new ArrayList<Character>();
keep.add('d');
keep.add('M');

for (FormatStyle style : styles) {
    for (Locale myLocale : locales) {
        String myPattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(style, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, myLocale);

        boolean separator = false;
        boolean copy = true;
        String newPattern = "";
        for (char c : myPattern.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '\'') {
                separator = !separator;
            }
            if (!separator) {
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                    if (keep.contains(c)) {
                        copy = true;
                    } else {
                        copy = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (copy) {
                newPattern = newPattern + c;
            }
        }

        char lastChar = newPattern.charAt(newPattern.length() - 1);
        while (!keep.contains(lastChar)) {
            if (lastChar == '\'') {
                newPattern = newPattern.substring(0, newPattern.length() - 1);
                newPattern = newPattern.substring(0, newPattern.lastIndexOf('\''));
            } else {
                newPattern = newPattern.substring(0, newPattern.length() - 1);
            }
            lastChar = newPattern.charAt(newPattern.length() - 1);
        }

        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(newPattern, myLocale).format(YearMonth.now()));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output would be:

```
6/30
Jun 30
June 30
June 30

30.06
30.06
30. Juni
30. Juni

30/06
30-jun
30 de junio
30 de junio

6/30
Jun 30
June 30
June 30
```

And for YearMonth:

```
6/16
Jun 2016
June 2016
June 2016

06.16
06.2016
Juni 2016
Juni 2016

06/16
jun-2016
junio de 2016
junio de 2016

6/16
Jun 2016
June 2016
June 2016
```

Comment: I don't think this is working. For example for `FormatStyle.MEDIUM` I get for `Locale` German `dd.MM.yyyy`, for English: `MMM d, yyyy` and for Spanish: `dd-MMM-yyyy`. How should I figure out which parts to remove from here? I mean there is `MMM` and `MM` or `dd` and `dd`. I don't even know the parts I want to keep...

Comment: This would be String handling, I'll add it in a second.

Comment: I've just added the requested function. It can probably be done several other ways and most likely better than I did.

Comment: I can not see how this should work. `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.ENGLISH)` gives me `MMM d, yyyy` not `MMM'x'd,'y'yyyy` or similiar. Why do you think it would be something like `MMM'x'dd'y'YYYY`? There are no `'` characters in the pattern - nor `'x'` or `'y'`....

Comment: It returns the pattern, for `FormatStyle.MEDIUM` and `Locale.ENGLISH` it does return `MMM d, yyyy`. But for `FormatStyle.LONG` and `new Locale("es","ES")` it returns `d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy`, so you need to be able to handle separators like '[whatever]'.

Comment: Yeah, so how should I know which seperator to use for each Locale/Style combination? There could be even differente seperators within one single pattern string...

Comment: I've just added a full example that should work with any format and locale, please go ahead and try it. Sorry about the poor explanations.

Comment: I will test it.However in german `30.06.16` should become `30.06.` (with the  trailing dot).

Comment: Also you probably want to remove any leading separators as well. E.g try with `keep.add('y'); keep.add('M');`

Comment: If you remove the while loop you will keep the trailing separator, although the I wouldn't keep it.

Comment: Also it could happen that you remove a part beetween two separators - so you end up two separator next to each other. E.g. try the `YearMonth` code with `Locale.US` - in this locale you get patterns for values like `6/30/16` so when removing the day you end up getting `6//16` having two slashes in between.

Comment: Please make sure you have the same code as the provided one removes the leading separator and doesn't keep two consecutive separators either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. However you made one mistake: You want to use `keep.add('y')` instead of `keep.add('Y')` (small `y`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! I will go with this solution for now. I will let you know if I run into any issues.

Comment: You are right, fixed. The approach I followed is to keep the separator after each kept field, and then remove trailing separators, as it makes most senses in the languages I know, but this may not apply to every language. For instance, would be good with a pattern like: "d ' day of ' MM ' month of 'YYYY"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)

**For `YearMonth`**

```
YearMonth source = YearMonth.now();
DateTimeFormatter english = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter german = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);

System.out.println(source.format(english));
System.out.println(source.format(german));
```

**For `MonthDay`**

```
MonthDay source = MonthDay.now();
DateTimeFormatter english = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter german = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MMMM", Locale.GERMAN);

System.out.println(source.format(english));
System.out.println(source.format(german));
```

Comment: I am aware of `ofPattern`. But, as in my examples above for `LocalDate`, I don't want to set the delimiter and ordering by myself. Java should decide for me what to use. It does for `LocalDate` - so why not for `YearMonth` and `MonthDay`?