# Localize string from `MonthDay` or `YearMonth` classes in java.time?

Tags: java, date, java-time, 2-digit-year

The java.time classes built into Java 8 and later offer the `MonthDay` and `YearMonth` classes. Their `toString` and `parse` methods use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats (`--MM-DD` & `YYYY-MM`), which is wise.

For presentation to humans, the standard formats may not be suitable. Is there anyway to generate an automatically localized string to represent the values in objects of either `MonthDay` or `YearMonth`?

For example, in the United States users might typically want MM/DD for month-day and MM/YY for year-month. While in the UK users might want DD/MM for month-day.

Anyway to automate such variations by [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) rather than explicitly define formatting patterns?

---

I tried the following code, using a date-oriented localizing formatter.

```
Locale l = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale ( l );

YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of ( 2017 , Month.JANUARY );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of ( Month.JANUARY , 29 );

String outputYm = ym.format ( f );
String outputMd = md.format ( f );
```

That code fails, throwing an exception when used for either `YearMonth` or `MonthDay`.

For `YearMonth`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth
    at java.time.YearMonth.getLong(YearMonth.java:494)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2540)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$LocalizedPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4347)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
    at java.time.YearMonth.format(YearMonth.java:1073)
    at javatimestuff.App.doIt(App.java:56)
    at javatimestuff.App.main(App.java:45)
```

For `MonthDay`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: YearOfEra
    at java.time.MonthDay.getLong(MonthDay.java:451)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2540)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$LocalizedPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4347)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
    at java.time.MonthDay.format(MonthDay.java:646)
    at javatimestuff.App.doIt(App.java:57)
    at javatimestuff.App.main(App.java:45)
```

Comment: Presumably you're looking for something related to `MonthDay.format(DateTimeFormatter)`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Added code to show that `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` fails in the `format()` methods of both `MonthDay` and `YearMonth`. If you have a variation that works, please post. I wonder if an Answer might lie in [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JDK-8168532](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168532). There needs an enhancement in the JDK to make this easy.

It is possible to do the work outside the JDK, but it is a lot of work. You have to parse the CLDR XML files (which are interlinked and have many references). Then you extract the relevant localized patterns for `MonthYear` and `YearMonth`, Then those patterns can be used to create a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Alternatively, you can hard code a map - `Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter>` - based on your business needs.

Comment: How likely are the chances JDK-8168532 will get fixed in Java 10?